# How to understand this decomposition of the spectrum of a QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, terminology, representation-theory, lie-algebra

The reference for this question is the following set of [notes on the conformal bootstrap](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.4290), section 1.2.2. Suppose we have a quantum field theory with symmetry algebra $\mathfrak g$ and spectrum $\mathcal S$. It is then stated that we can decompose the spectrum as follows $$\mathcal S = \bigoplus_{\mathcal R} m_{\mathcal R}\mathcal R,$$ where $\mathcal R$ are the representations of this symmetry algebra and $m_{\mathcal R}\in \mathbb N\cup \{\infty\}$   is the multiplicity of the representation $\mathcal R$. However, these two things on either side of the equal sign are two completely different things. On the LHS, we have a vector space, and on the RHS we have a direct sum over all such representations of the symmetry algebra of this vector space (i.e., all homomorphisms $\mathcal R:\mathfrak g\to \mathfrak{gl}(V)$, for $V$ a vector space). How can one then make sense of this equality, seeing as these objects are so different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $G$ be a group. Most of the time in Physics will be a Lie group but it need not be for this discussion. A representation $G$ is a pair $(V,\rho)$ where $V$ is a vector space and $\rho:G\to{\rm GL}(V)$ is a group homomorphism. It maps elements of $G$ into invertible linear operators acting on $V$.

In particular, we can define the direct sum of representations. Let $(V,\rho)$ and $(V',\rho')$ be two representations. The direct sum is the representation $(V\oplus V',\rho\oplus \rho')$.

$$(\rho\oplus \rho')(g) (v,w)=(\rho(g)v,\rho'(g)w).\tag{1}$$

The same construction can be carried out for Lie algebras $\mathfrak{g}$ and their representations.

The point is that both sides of your equality are representations, and we have a definition for the direct sum of two representations: we take the direct sum of the vector spaces and endow it with the group action defined in (1) or its Lie algebra analog in the case of representation of algebras.

In particular, your equality means that the vector space on the right-hand side decomposes as a direct sum of the vector spaces of the representations appearing on the right-hand side.

Comment: So to be more specific, we should say that the spectrum is a direct sum of the representation spaces of all the representations of the symmetry algebra? Because the way we define the spectrum does not make it explicit that it is the representation space for some representation $\mathcal R$ of $\mathfrak g$.

Comment: I took a look into the notes and to be honest his terminology is not quite standard in my opinion. What he defines as the spectrum in page 10 is basically the Hilbert space ${\cal H}$ of a quantum-mechanical system whose elements are the quantum states. Now, whenever your system admits a symmetry group $G$ or symmetry algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ the associated Hilbert space must carry a unitary representation of that symmetry, and it, therefore, makes sense to decompose it into irreps. See for example Weinberg's The Quantum Theory of Fields Chapter 2.

Comment: Ah, I am obviously just beginning to learn the theory, so I wouldn't have known. Thanks for the heads up. So, what then is the standard definition of the spectrum? Also, do you have any resource recommendations for conformal field theory/bootstrap?

Comment: It depends on the context. In general Quantum Mechanics, given one observable ${\cal O}$ we usually call spectrum of ${\cal O}$ the set of eigenvalues of ${\cal O}$. In Conformal Field Theory it is common to call spectrum of the theory the set of conformal dimensions of a basis of primary operators together with the spin representation in which they transform (and possibly representation of other symmetries as well). The Hilbert space of a quantum system is usually called the state space or just "the system's Hilbert space".

Comment: Yeah, I was familiar with the terminology in QM and functional analysis. Thanks for elaborating.

Comment: About resources. Well, these notes you are using are probably nice, although I have never read them before. Then we have the canonical reference which is the yellow book: "Conformal Field Theory" by Di Francesco. There's also the lectures by David Simmons-Duffin https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.07982.

Comment: Okay, thanks for those references, I have started to watch the lectures by Simmons-Duffin, although I am not too far in.

Comment: Also, this year there was a very nice course given in the conformal bootstrap. Apparently, the lectures were recorded and you may find them here https://higgs.ph.ed.ac.uk/workshops/higgs-centre-school-2022/. But definitely, it depends on what you want. For example, as far as I recall, Simmons-Duffin lectures do not cover WZW-related stuff. But then you may find relevant material in the yellow book.

Comment: Awesome! I'll check those out.